# Magento 2 How to make "Save" button same as "Save & Close" on product add/edit?

Tags: magento2, product

I need to make the "**Save**" button same as "**Save & Close**" on the product add/edit in admin?

**I need both buttons will behave the same. (when click on save it will save the product and go to the product list)**

How could I achieve this functionality with a custom module?